# The expected size of a subtree of any labelled rooted tree

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, expectation

Consider the set of labelled rooted trees of size $n$, $\mathcal{T}_n$. Let $r$ be the root of each tree $T=(V,E)\in\mathcal{T}$, $r\in V(T)$, and let $n(u)$ be the number of vertices of the subtree $T(u)$ of $T$ (then, $n(r)=n=|V(T)|$, and $n(l)=1$ if $l\in V$ is a leaf of $T$). For any such tree $n(u)$ is easy to compute.

I would like to know whether there are results on the expected size of a subtree (chosen uniformly at random) of a labelled rooted tree, over the space of uniformly random labelled rooted trees. I'm interested in both closed-form formulae and the methods used for their derivation since I need to evaluate other expected values over the same space of trees. I'm mostly interested in exact formulae, but asymptotic results are also welcome. My search on the internet has been fruitless so far, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you choosing $u$? Is it that you are choosing a uniformly random $T$ and then choosing a uniformly random $u$ from it?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention this. Both the tree $T$ and the vertex $u$ are chosen uniformly at random.

Comment: Ok.  Just a quick note, in case it helps your searching, is that this is equal to the expected distance from a uniformly chosen vertex to the root: \begin{align*}\sum_T \sum_{v \in T} \sum_{w \geq v} 1 &= \sum_T \sum_{w \in T} \sum_{v \leq w} 1 \\ &= \sum_{T} \sum_{w \in T} |w| \end{align*}

Comment: Yes. But be careful. For a path graph of 3 vertices rooted at the central vertex, we have that $\sum_{u\in V} n(u)=5$. If we use distances $d(u)$ to the root expressed in edges the summation becomes $\sum_{u\in V} n(u)= \sum_{u\in V} (1 + d(u))$. We could also express the distance in number of vertices, considering the vertex itself, i.e., define the distance from $u$ to $r$ as the number of edges from $u$ to $r$ plus 1 (vertex $u$ -- or vertex $r$).

Comment: You're right, I'm off by $1$, so it's the expected distance plus $1$.

Comment: The limiting distribution of the heights of vertices of a random labelled tree was found by Rényi and Szekeres. See https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C30DF2A9C26541526D847E0A0D46F2A8/S1446788700004432a.pdf/on_the_height_of_trees.pdf.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I'll get into the details as soon as I can.